# Getting {"errorMessage": "'httpMethod'", "errorType": "KeyError"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Using Lambda function to Get and post request. While testing it gives error
{"errorMessage": "'httpMethod'", "errorType": "KeyError", "requestId": "435e6811-acc5-4bc7-b009-377bc6178bb8", "stackTrace": ["  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 11, in lambda_handler\n    if event['httpMethod'] == 'GET':\n"]} :

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('ApigatewayDynamo')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("event", event)

    if event['httpMethod'] == 'GET':
        name = event['queryStringParameters']['name']
        response = table.get_item(Key={'name': name})
        print(response)
        print(response['Item'])
        
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(response['Item'])
        }
        
    if event['httpMethod'] == 'POST':
        body = json.loads(event['body'])
        print('body', body)
        name = body.get('name')
        print('Name is ', name)
        if name is None:
            return {
                'statusCode': 400,
                'body': json.dumps("Check the payload/ method")
           }
        table.put_item(Item=body)
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps("Name added successfully")
               }

        return {
            'statusCode': 400,
            'body': json.dumps("Check the payload/ method/ Lambda function")
            }
```

The Dynamo db table has name as primary key and the json testing data is

```
{
    "name": "Kaira",
    "Phone Number": 98777
}
```

What is to be done to resolve this?

I am trying to insert the data from post method and get the data from Get method.

Comment: What is the actual value of your `event`?

Answer (score 1):

This error happens before you even read from DynamoDB.

You are getting a key error while trying to parse the `event` object. Have a look at your `event` object and ensure the path of the values your are trying to resolve from it are correct.

If that fails, share the value of `event` here and we can guide you better.

I also strongly suggest wrapping API requests in try catch/except blocks

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB attribute names are case sensitive - the attribute name "Name" which you write is not the as the attribute name "name" which you try to read.

Comment: Even when I change the Name to "name" everywhere, I still get the same error

Comment: Please share the **schema** of your table (how you created it). Was the key column you defined when creating the table called "Name" or "name"?
Also please try to see if you can get a slightly longer error message from DynamoDB and not just "KeyError".

Answer (score 0):

The get request is also fetching the data now, the detail error was decimal was not getting serialised.

Got it worked out by importing simplejson as json

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).